# Win 10 inaccessible, stuck in 1920x1080 144Hz

Tags: windows-10, dvi, displayport, refresh-rate

I have one installation of Windows 10 which I set at 144Hz because I have an AOC G2460 monitor and a GTX970. However, the DisplayPort cable I used has apparently given up the ghost, so whenever I try to get in all the monitor shows is a black screen. I have an older Win 7 installation on a hard drive and using it and a DVI cable I can 'peer' into the SSD containing the Win 10 install, so it looks like everything is fine inside.

Is there any way I can fiddle with the Win 10 installation from 'from outside,' as it were, so I can dial the resolution back down to 1920x1080 60Hz so my DVI cable and monitor can handle it?

Comment: Do you have a lower-spec monitor available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that doesn't require network access.

- *Step 1:* Download [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
- *Step 2:* Create a batch file (with the `.cmd` file extension) with the following content:
  `nircmd setdisplay 800 600 24`
- *Step 3:* Place both batch file and the exe in the same directory on the WIndows 10 disk.
- *Step 4:* Create a shortcut to the batch file and place it in the startup folder on the Windows 10 disk (usually found at `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
   for the current user, and `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp` for all users)

The next time that you start Windows 10, the resolution should automatically get changed on startup.

*Further Reading:*
[How can I change screen resolution from command prompt in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/a/1180063/432540)
[NirCmd Command Reference - setdisplay](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setdisplay.html)

---

**EDIT**
Okay, so this won't work if the account has a password since the commands are run after the user is logged in. In this case, you could wait for a while till you're sure that the PC is switched on, then use this sequence to log in:

`<spacebar> - [password] - <enter>`

If there are multiple users on the system:
`<spacebar> - [username] - <tab> - [password] - <enter>`

Comment: I recommend using Ctrl or another key that doesn’t produce characters to clear away to lock screen wallpaper.

Comment: @DanielB That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to that system via a network, you can change it from powershell:

```
Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768 -Freq 60 -Force
```

If you cannot access the system, you will need to restart it, use a boot disk, Press Shift + F10 there to open the command prompt when the installation screen appears and then type

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy
```

After that, restart and you will be able to press **F8** at start-up and choose **enable low resolution video**.

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest*, user-friendly ways would be:

1. From another computer on the same network as the one with the problem, Remote Desktop into the computer and fix the screen resolution that way. You'll have to use the [/admin switch](https://superuser.com/a/237647/144607) of `mstsc` program (Start -> Run... `mstsc /admin`).
2. Boot up into Safe Mode; it should revert to a lower resolution.

Note, Windows 10 does not appear to store display settings in the registry anymore, so the old trick of editing the registry will probably not work.

Comment: That did it! Hmm, handy little thing, this nircmd. I knew and used other Nirsoft stuff, but it's good to know this exists. Thanks! Now to make that emergency boot disk . . . .